# Resharper does not discover my NUnit tests in a UWP UnitTestProject

Tags: unit-testing, uwp, nunit, resharper, dotcover

using Visual studio 2017 community 15.6.4
Resharper 2018.2 with dotcover 2018.2.3

What I did :
Create a Universal Window UnitTestProject App.
Reference in there, via nuget, the following packages :

- Nunit
- Nunit3TestAdapter

Then I create a NUnit Test function in the TestClass :

```
[Test]
public void NunitTest()
{
}
```

I compile the sln And then ask Resharper to list my tests.
It returns nothing, and there is no Test-shortcut icon in front of my test function.

**How can I have Resharper discover the NUnit tests in a UWP Application or library ?**

Note : visual studio Test explorer finds and runs the sample MStest function that was created in the Test App. It also displays my NUnit test, but can't run it (error : No test is available in entrypoint\UnitTestProject1.exe. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.)

Answer (score 0):

According to [the issue](https://github.com/nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter/issues/322) on the NUnit repo on GitHub, NUnit does not support UWP.